# Generic class implicit T

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic Command of type `ICommand`:

```
class SimpleCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    public SimpleCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    /*
        All the other stuff...
    */
}
```

Used like this:

```
ICommand command = new SimpleCommand<string>(MyMethod);

private void MyMethod(string arg) { ... }
```

When using i would like the compiler to automaticly pick up the T from the Action passed, so i can just write like tihs:

```
ICommand command = new SimpleCommand(MyMethod);
```

However if i write like so, i get an compiler error. Is it possible to make the compiler pick up the T class from the Method parameter type ?

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: Incorrect number of type parameters in reference to class 'SimpleCommand<T>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement static `Create` method.

```
public static class Command
{
    public static SimpleCommand<T> Create<T>(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null)
    {
        return new SimpleCommand<T>(execute, canExecute);
    }
}
```

That should allow compiler to pick up the generic argument when called like:

```
ICommand command = Command.Create(MyMethod);
```

Comment: It should be `...= Command.Create...`, not `...= new Command.Create...`

Answer (score 2):

Not for a constructor, but you could implement the factory pattern which could instantiate the correct type based on the argument